# RegEx fails to capture groups in loops

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Regex search fails to get a string from match object when being used in a for loop.

```
row_values = result_script_name.split('^')
    for row in row_values:
        table_name = re.search(r"(?<=')(.*)(?=')", row).group(0)
```

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

But the same regex pattern finds string perfectly fine when used outside the loop.

```
table_name = re.search(r"(?<=')(.*)(?=')", row_values[0]).group(0)
```

The string I wanted was to get "lifetime" outof below string

```
^WORKFLOW_NAME='lifetime'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what is happening is that certain rows do not match at all, and therefore you are trying to access a capture group (the zeroth one, in this case), which does not even exist.  Here is the pattern you should be using:

```
input = "^WORKFLOW_NAME='lifetime'"
match = re.search(r"(?<=')(.*)(?=')", input)
if match:
    print(match.group(0))
```

That is, you should first be checking if the call to `search` were successful, and only then print.  I don't know exactly what your loop is supposed to be doing, but you can easily enough adapt the above script to your needs.

Comment: With the newly `walrus` operator (Python >= 3.8) you can finally do sth. like `if (match := re.search(...)) is not None:`. Yippeh! (Well, `PHP` had this since like 1990...).

Answer (score 0):

Here, we might want to simplify our expression, maybe to something similar to:

```
.+?'(.+?)'
```

where our data is saved in the capturing group `\\1`

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r".+'(.+?)'"

test_str = "^WORKFLOW_NAME='lifetime'"

subst = "\\1"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/OqT0sq/1)

[image]

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/OqT0sq/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Demo

```js
const regex = /.+?'(.+?)'/gm;
const str = `^WORKFLOW_NAME='lifetime'
WORKFLOW_NAME='Any other data that we want'
WORKFLOW_NAME='Any other data that we want'`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```